# Reading from MySqlReader

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

For some reason, I couldn't find a good answer in google why this code dosent work:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Databaseyeshuv1");
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
MySqlDataReader Reader;
command.CommandText =
  "SELECT * FROM `MASADE_FEA_bak2` WHERE `marom_num`        equals `3`";
connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
{
  string line = Reader.GetString(1);
  this.שטח_קומה_מחושב.Text = line;
}
connection.Close();
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to      specification starting at index 0. at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) at MyApp7.UI.Controls.ShowMASADE_FEA_bak2.KomotMASADE_FEA_bak2TableControlRow.Setשטח_קומה_מחושב()

Comment: `new MySqlConnection("Databaseyeshuv1");` - what is thát?

Comment: that's the connection string from WebConfig

Comment: Quite apart from anything else, the equality operator in MySQL is not `equals`, but [`=`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made many mistake in your code:

1. The string `"Databaseyeshuv1"` should be the connection string value, not the name. You should write some code to get that value from config file. Have a look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx)
2. In your command text, should use `=` instead of `equals` and remove the character quoting `3`, so just use number 3 only.

Comment: If I just enter the full connection string instead of "Databaseyeshuv1", is it a problem or wrong codeing? It works anyway, Thank you!

Comment: If you do that, you will do the same thing in some codes on another methods later. If you're afraid of reading connection string from the config file, create a constant is better.